# Efficiency of std::tuple and std::map

Tags: c++, optimization, maps, tuples

I am currently building a program that relies on multiple vectors and maps to retain previously computed information. My vectors are of the standard format, and not very interesting. The maps are of the form

```
std::map<std::string, long double>
```

with the intent of the string being a parseable mapping of one vector onto another, such as

```
std::map<std::string, long double> rmMap("fvProperty --> fvTime", 3.0234);
```

where I can later on split the string and compare the substrings to the vector names to figure out which ones were involved in getting the number. 
However, I have recently found that std::tuple is available, meaning I can skip the string entirely and use the vector positions instead with

```
std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, long double>
```

This allows me (as far as I can tell) to use both the first and the second value as a key, which seems preferable to parsing a string for my indices.

My crux is that I am unaware of the efficiency here. There will be *a lot* of calls to these tuples/maps, and efficacy is of the essence, as the program is expected to run for weeks before producing an end result.

Thus, I would ask you if tuples are more or equally efficient (in terms of memory, cache, and cycles) than maps when it comes to large and computationally intense programs.

EDIT:
If tuples cannot be used in this way, would the map

```
std::map<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, long double>
```

be an effective substitute to using strings for identification?

Comment: A tuple isn't a replacement for a map; it's just a simple structure with (in this case) three data members. If you want to use two values as a map key, you'll want something like `map<pair<int,int>,double>`. You may or may not find `unordered_map` to be more efficient than `map`, depending on exactly what you're doing with them.

Comment: You will, of course, have to provide a suitable comparison function so that `map` can order things properly.  Or, if you don't need an ordered map, you can use `unordered_map` and provide an appropriate hashing function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  We typed past each other.  :-) You edited your comment to say pretty much what I was adding to your comment.

Comment: I guess it is best to write a small test app to see how you speed compares? Shall I write one?

Comment: How do you plan on accessing this structure later?  Iterating through the whole thing?  Querying primarily by both vector indices?  By one of the vector indices?  Your answer will decide the proper structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of the map is to efficiently query data associated to a key.

It cannot be compared to tuples which just pack values together: you will have to travel tuples yourself to retrieve the correct value.

Using a `map<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, long double>` as Mike suggests is probably the way to go.

Comment: Then I shall try this. Hopefully it will prove faster than what I am currently doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples and Maps are used for very different purposes. So it should be primarily about what you want to use them for, not how efficient they are. You'll have some trouble to turn on your car with a screw driver, as you will have trying to fix a screw with your car keys. I'd advice against both.

A tuple is *one* little dataset, in your case e.g. the set `{1,2,3.0234}`. A map is for mapping *multiple* keys to their values. In fact, a map internally consists of multiple tuples (pairs), each one containing a key and the associated value. Inside the map, the pairs are arranged in a way that makes searching for the keys easy.

In your case, I'd prefer the `map<pair<int, int>, double>` as your edit suggests. The keys (i.e. the vector index pairings) are much easier to search for and "parse" than those strings.